# Alterar o parâmetro de um método em java

Tags: java, método

Estou desenvolvendo um código que utiliza criptografia ECC. Estou usando o seguinte código:

```
import java.security.*;
import java.security.spec.*;

public class Teste {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
            KeyPairGenerator kpg;
            kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("EC","SunEC");
            ECGenParameterSpec ecsp;
            ecsp = new ECGenParameterSpec("secp256r1");
            kpg.initialize(ecsp);
            KeyPair kp = kpg.genKeyPair();
            PrivateKey privKey = kp.getPrivate();
            PublicKey pubKey = kp.getPublic();
            System.out.println(pubKey.toString());
  }
}
```

A saída mostrada no console é a seguinte:

```
Sun EC public key, 256 bits
  public x coord: 4615855875618351712635877256976103420366861757278971514413945892411643339267
  public y coord: 86295372175394984599678936024544037153778609141128039300731169643337680519305
```

Tentei alterar algumas coisas no código porém vi que esse modelo de print deve vir de algum método especifico (`KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("EC","SunEC");` ou `new ECGenParameterSpec("secp256r1");`).

Como faço para acessar esse método e alterar o print para mostrar apenas os números e desconsiderar o texto mostrado? Queria que o dado obtido com o método `getPublic();` ficasse no formato abaixo:

```
4615855875618351712635877256976103420366861757278971514413945892411643339267
86295372175394984599678936024544037153778609141128039300731169643337680519305
```

Comment: `PublicKey` é uma interface, e o tipo retornado pelo `KeyPairGenerator` é um detalhe de implementação que pode variar de acordo com a JVM usada, os providers de criptografia que vc está usando, etc. Vc até poderia ver o tipo com `pubKey.getClass()`, fazer um *cast* para este tipo e ver se ele tem métodos específicos para retornar estes dados, mas não é garantido (e o tipo específico pode mudar de acordo com a JVM, então é melhor não ficar preso à estas implementações internas). Talvez seja mais fácil usar `substring` no resultado de `pubKey.toString()` e extrair o que vc precisa...

Comment: Consegui, obrigado!